Mobile Safari browser fails to go online after failed requests
I'm having trouble with a web application that stops working when internet drops for a sufficient amount of time (this only happens on ios, not android, mac or windows). Specifically it is a form type application where users complete fields and there is an autosave functionality that will save the progress every x seconds.
When the internet is switched off initially, the requests take a while to timeout and during this period if you switch on the internet again everything continues working as expected. It's only after about 5 requests (with internet switched off) where it seems like the browser starts caching the failed response and the error thrown in the console is "Failed to load resource: The internet connection appears to be offline", after this, switching the internet back on has no effect. Even then refreshing the page results in safari displaying a "Not connected to the internet message" all while at the same time being able to access the internet on the device (other websites still work).
I first thought this simply had something to do with caching, however even after setting a couple of different headers (using axios):
const headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Expires': '0'
  }

It had absolutely no effect. Trying to set a shorter timeout on the request also did not help. I also tried to make a separate small health-check request that would serve to check whether the server is reachable but this request encounters the same problem.
The application was initially served as a pwa and a serviceWorker was registered however I removed this since it is not crucial, thinking that might have had something to do with it. Also tried cancelling the axios request.
Here is a code pen that gives the same result. When you switch the internet off for a while and then back on the requests keep failing: https://codepen.io/General_Patches/pen/KKYBjqb
